# how to resolve google play warning “Use of SMS or Call Log ”,

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

my app It does not have the `SMS` or `CALL LOG` permission, but i have the warning, all permissions  in my app
`android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_ST"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning could be coming from an active previously uploaded apk, in some of the release channels. [Check if this solves your issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391621/google-play-services-sms-and-call-logs-permission-issue/55392826#55392826)