# Google play services SMS and CALL LOGS permission issue

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, sms

We had an application on google play that was having read/receive SMS permissions defined and it was working fine , later on google made restriction to applications that they cannot use SMS and call log permissions until and unless they are their core functionalities. As per policy we remove both read and receive permissions from our application manifest as well as from code base.And tried to upload a compliant version on google play but it is still showing a form thinking that we are still using those permissions in our application. There is no way on google play to tell that we are not using these permissions and don't show this form.The form pic is below please suggest if anyone faced any issue like this . Thanks guys.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Comment: @Zoe I don't think so its off-topic its a tech community and i am sure i am posting on the right place if you don't have answer you don't need to put a comment. Thanks

Comment: [meta disagrees](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). This is a programming community btw, not a general tech community

Comment: @Zoe So where is the right place ?

Comment: Nowhere in the SE network. You'll have to find a different site on your own. Reddit can be a place to start though. Alternatively there's [chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Just because you get an answer doesn't make the question on-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some previous apk in some release channels, which had the permissions. Do the following:

1. Go to Artifact Library under Release Management on the sidebar of your app dashboard.
2. Check if there are any previous apks under Active artifacts.
3. If you find any previous apk, that is the one causing the "Previously declared permissions" on your release page. Remove this, and you are all good!

Comment: Exactly that was the reason there was an apk in Beta channel that had that permission still in it and we updated its version as well to latest and moved to production and now all good. Thanks you saved us !